# want to implement owl carousel but but but

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to create a website using django and bootstrap. I am extending base.html into index.html. I have implemented navbar(from bootstrap) in base.html and want to implement owl carousel in index.html. Both base.html and index.html are in templates folder of my project. I tried placing css and js files like owl.carousel etc in

```html
<!-- THIS IS base.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/owl.theme.green.min.css">

  <script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <title>BURGERZONE-{% block title %} {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <h1>BURGERZONE</h1>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/menu">Menu<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Today's special
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  {% block body %}
  {% endblock body %}

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

templates folder,static folder, created separate folder but nothing worked. Tried removing and adding forward slash/ in path every possible way that i know of

```html
<!-- THIS IS index.html-->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
    </div>

{% endblock body %}
```

I AM GETTING FOLLOWING ERROR SEEN IN CONSOLE AFTER PRESSING F12

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgD7n.png

    jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/:126:26)
    at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2:30211)
    at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2:30513) undefined
E.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2
jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):126)
    at e (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
:8000/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am locally adding Javascript files

i don't need add them again just before body tag ends. So i removed javascript files added at the end of body tag and it worked perfectly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/owl.theme.green.min.css">

  <script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <title>BURGERZONE-{% block title %} {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <h1>BURGERZONE</h1>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/menu">Menu<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Today's special
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  {% block body %}
  {% endblock body %}

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add owl.carousel.min.js file in your home page and before the file in which you are using add the following code:

```
<script defer src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>
```

--

```
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true
      });
```

Try this way,the recommended way in Django for loading static files by using this way

```
{% load static %}
<!-- THIS IS base.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.green.min.css' %}">

  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>

  <title>BURGERZONE-{% block title %} {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <h1>BURGERZONE</h1>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/menu">Menu<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Today's special
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  {% block body %}
  {% endblock body %}

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
<script defer src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

all other code write same I'm not compile the code just tell you if you feel any problem feel free to ask

Comment: your method worked only a little. slide were shown with numbers that is from 1 to 12 but navigation buttons were still missing. A thought came to my mind. As I am locally adding Javascript ' <script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> ' files i don't need add them again just before body tag ends. So i removed javascript files added at the end of body tag and it worked perfectly. But still thank you for your effort and time

Comment: no problem any where you add I write just imagine code debug it ,so you tell me more I help you no problem what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgD7n.png

This error comes when you not initialize the owl carousel.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 4, // no. of items
    nav: true, // if you want navigation arrows make it true otherwise false
    dots: true // if you want pagination dots make it true otherwise false
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```